# How to create real-time WASD control over an Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, keyboard

I am trying to figure out how to use the WASD keys on my computer, to go through the USB cable and then spin the Arduino servos in real-time. So if I press the “a” key, it should start to move left with little time delay. How do I do this?

Comment: do it is steps ... first write code to get data from the PC to the arduino .... when you are successful, add code to move servos

Comment: why this way? you could start some serial terminal program which sends the character immediately, but much simpler is to put 4 buttons on breadboard or to use a small joystick

Comment: In any case you need some software on your PC to send the key events to the Arduino. The simplest solution can be the Serial Monitor of the IDE. Try this and if you have problems with the Arduino sketch, feel free to [edit] your questions. BTW, you might like to take the [tour] and learn [ask].